# FireFoxDriver JavaScript errors does not show in FireFox browser

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox

I'm using the following code to capture JavaScript errors when running Selenium tests:

```
public static void AssertNoJavaScriptErrorsInLog(this RemoteWebDriver driver)
{
    var errorStrings = new List<string> { "SyntaxError", "EvalError", "ReferenceError", "RangeError", "TypeError", "URIError" };

    var jsErrors = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser).Where(x => errorStrings.Any(e => x.Message.Contains(e))).ToList();

    if (jsErrors.Any())
    {
        Assert.Fail("JavaScript error(s):" + Environment.NewLine + jsErrors.Aggregate("", (s, entry) => s + entry.Message + Environment.NewLine));
    }
}
```

One of my tests intermittently reports an error:

```
Assert.Fail failed. JavaScript error(s):
TypeError: doc.documentElement is null
TypeError: doc.documentElement is null
```

Trying to locate the error I look in the console of the FireFox browser which just ran the failed tests, but it's empty!

Why can't I see the JavaScript error in the browser console?

Comment: Could you check if Chrome would behave the same way? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I couldn't reproduce the error using ChromeDriver.

Comment: Okay, what selenium and firefox versions are you using? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Im using Selenium 2.52.0.0 and Firefox 45.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be experiencing the following *fresh* selenium issue:

- [Some new browser logs are not captured](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1914)

As a workaround, consider *downgrading selenium to 2.52*.

---

Also, from time to time there are *compatibility issues between selenium and firefox* with a wide range of symptoms - play around with firefox versions (you can download older versions [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)) and see if you still cannot catch the js error on the console.

Comment: Interesting! Could also perhaps be related to issue [Subsequent calls to browser.manage().logs().get('browser') always yield empty array responses](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3087)

Comment: @Drutten yeah, this would leads to the external selenium problem. Have you tried with, say, 2.52, 2.51 and older seleniums - still reproducible? Thanks.